# How to pass bind variable (parameter) of decimal type when value is zero?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I am using bind variables with the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess provider. The table column I am binding to is defined simply as a "number". The line of code below works fine when the variable named AMOUNT is non-zero. But when AMOUNT is 0, I get the error below. I have searched the web (and SO) and didn't find any help. What am I doing wrong?

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("TIME_AMOUNT", OracleDbType.Decimal, AMOUNT.ToString("#.##"), ParameterDirection.Input);
```

> Message=One of the identified items was in an invalid format.
>   Source=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess   StackTrace:
>          at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal..ctor(String numStr)
>          at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleParameterImpl.SetDecimalDataInBytes(Object
>   paramValue, Byte[]& decimalByteArray)
>          at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleParameterImpl.SetDecimalDataInBytes(Object
>   paramValue)
>          at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind_Decimal()

Comment: Why are you telling the parameter it will hold a decimal (OracleDbType.Decimal) then passing it a string (AMOUNT.ToString("#.##"))? This could be your problem.

Comment: Whart is the purpose of AMOUNT.ToString("#.##")?

Comment: AMOUNT is a double. But doubles can sometimes have a rounding issue, hence I use the .ToString("#.##") to clean off the errant decimal places.

Comment: @Kevin - you may be onto something...but it works with non-zero values.

Comment: If it is otherwise working, maybe try "#.00" or "0.00" as your formatting pattern. It may be passing "0" for zero, which may be the issue.

Comment: @Kevin Aha! You were on the right track. It appears as if my "ToString("#.##")" was returning an empty string for zero. I changed it to "ToString("0.##")" and it now works! Thanks!

Comment: You may want to consider using an OracleDecimal datatype which allows you to set the precision more accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if my "ToString("#.##")" was returning an empty string for zero. I changed it to "ToString("0.##")" and it now works!
(Thanks to @Kevin for the tip that led to the answer! I should have posted this answer long ago...but better late then never.)